# Declaring local variable in function from another list

Tags: scheme, racket, let

I'm trying to define an element according to given values from another list

```
  (define foo   ; not working but this is general idea
    (λ (x ys)
      (for/list ([y ys])
        (if (eq? x (car y))
            (let ('x (cdr y))
              (boolean? x))  ; x not passed, returns #f
            '()))))   ; or use x to do something like (eval ('and x #t))
```

Desired output:

```
>(foo 'a '((a . true) (b . false)))
#t
```

to show the boolean of `(cdr y)` actually passes onto x (just an example that I'm trying)

Algorithm - search through `ys` for which `(car y)` of each element in `ys` to be equal to `a` and set the boolean `(cdr y)` to `a`. So the above `x` should have boolean `#t`.

Not quite understanding why it doesn't work.

Comment: The machine-interpreted meaning of the expression `(let ('x (cdr y)) ...)` is probably wildly different from what you meant. It's equivalent to `(let ([quote x] [cdr y]) ...)`, where you're saying let `quote` = `x` and let `cdr` = `y`. You probably meant `(let ([x (cdr y)]) ...)` which says let `x` = `(cdr y)`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing my best to understand your problem, but it's not totally clear what your objective is.

It looks like you're trying to return a single `#t`/`#f` value, but if you look at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html) for `for/list`, you'll see that it will always return a list.

Let's try something like this instead

```
(define (foo x ys)
  (let loop ([ys ys])
    (cond [(empty? ys) '()]
          [(eq? x (caar ys)) (cdar ys)]
          [else (loop (cdr ys))])))

(foo 'a '((a . true) (b . false))) ;=> 'true
(foo 'b '((a . true) (b . false))) ;=> 'false
```

However, if you want to convert `'true` to `#t` and `'false` to `#f`, you could add a helper function like so

```
(define (bool x)
  (eq? 'true x))

(define (foo x ys)
  (let loop ([ys ys])
    (cond [(empty? ys) '()]
          [(eq? x (caar ys)) (bool (cdar ys))]
          [else (loop (cdr ys))])))

(foo 'a '((a . true) (b . false))) ;=> #t
(foo 'b '((a . true) (b . false))) ;=> #f
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that there is a `dict-ref` and is what I needed.